# Playing with public/private keys on the command line

Tags: public-key-encryption, private-key

I want to play with public/private keys just for fun.
I want to use shorter strings, just to see the magic in front of my eyes.
Example:

"Text_merry_X-mas" + small_key1 -> "any_small_unreadable_string"

"any_small_unreadable_string" + key2 -> "Text_merry_X-mas"

I do not care if the algorithm is RSA or anything else.
I just want to give this inputs and get outputs on the command line.
I do not want to encrypt files and let RSA calculate that long keys,
because again it is just for fun.

And i would like to be able to define key1, as we do for passwords.
Than let key2 be calculated from key1.

Can you guys give me some tips?
Thx a los!

Comment: Any particular language you'd like to use...?

Comment: No, no particular language. The most important is to be able to play with those strings on the command line. For didatical purposes, for my own learning, to have some fun with these stuff...

Answer (score 0):

Broadly:

For Asymmetric encryption you must first generate your private key and extract the public key.

```
openssl genrsa -aes256 -out private.key 8912
openssl rsa -in private.key -pubout -out public.key
```

To encrypt:

```
openssl rsautl -encrypt -pubin -inkey public.key -in plaintext.txt -out encrypted.txt
```

To decrypt:

```
openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey private.key -in encrypted.txt -out plaintext.txt
```

This and more nicely summarized here: https://gist.github.com/dreikanter/c7e85598664901afae03fedff308736b

Comment: Thx a lot. Good tip!